# Maria DB GROUP BY id DESC with IN magic

Tags: mysql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

Tried get "ORDER BY id DESC" in "GROUP BY" to get only last comment.
When i use "IN" with >1 elements its works fine, but with one element or without "IN".
My MariaDB version is 10.0.36-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is examples: 56xxx - true ids, 55xxx false ids

```
   MariaDB [shop]> SELECT `commentsapi_comment`.`id` FROM `commentsapi_comment`
      WHERE (`commentsapi_comment`.`orderid`='6576') GROUP BY orderid DESC;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 55811 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [shop]> SELECT `commentsapi_comment`.`id` FROM `commentsapi_comment`
     WHERE (`commentsapi_comment`.`orderid` IN ('6576')) GROUP BY orderid DESC;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 55811 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [shop]> SELECT `commentsapi_comment`.`id` FROM `commentsapi_comment`
      WHERE (`commentsapi_comment`.`orderid` IN ('6576','6576')) GROUP BY orderid DESC;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 56218 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [shop]> SELECT `commentsapi_comment`.`id` FROM `commentsapi_comment`
      WHERE (`commentsapi_comment`.`orderid` IN ('6576','-1')) GROUP BY orderid DESC;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 56218 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [shop]> SELECT `commentsapi_comment`.`id` FROM `commentsapi_comment`
      WHERE (`commentsapi_comment`.`orderid` IN ('6576')) GROUP BY orderid DESC;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 55811 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [shop]> SELECT `commentsapi_comment`.`id` FROM `commentsapi_comment`
      WHERE (`commentsapi_comment`.`orderid` IN ('6576','6577')) GROUP BY orderid DESC;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 56199 |
| 56218 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [shop]> SELECT `commentsapi_comment`.`id` FROM `commentsapi_comment`
      WHERE (`commentsapi_comment`.`orderid` IN ('6577')) GROUP BY orderid DESC;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 55813 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Who knows reason of this?

Comment: `GROUP BY DESC` makes no sense to me. Group by is for aggregations and order of aggregations is generally not relevant.

Comment: "GROUP BY DESC makes no sense to me. Group by is for aggregations and order of aggregations is generally not relevant." @apokryfos well MySQL supports `GROUP BY DESC` but is deprecated in the newer MySQL versions (5.7+) .. Also the older MySQL versions (5.7 or lower) auto sort `GROUP BY <group>` like you are using `GROUP BY <group> ORDER BY <group> ASC`..

Comment: i see invalid ANSI GROUP BY SQL queries.. You are using a column in the SELECT which is not in the GROUP BY

Comment: @Raymond Nijland i need to sort by id col and group by orderid col, select with * gives some results as without

Comment: How about doing `SELECT MAX(id) FROM commentsapi_comment ... GROUP BY orderid;` ?

Comment: @apokryfos i tried it too but in project i need all columns from this id, not only one

Comment: As @RaymondNijland you need to use ANSI GROUP BY SQL queries. As it stands you're trying to use `GROUP BY` as a way to filter data but that's not what it's there for. The purpose of `GROUP BY` is to aggregate data.

Comment: @apokryfos ansi functions don't have functionality to resolve my problem with one query

Comment: @apokryfos - `GROUP BY x DESC` is a MySQL extension.  It is a little-used contraction for `GROUP BY x  ORDER BY x DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

That's an invalid use of `GROUP BY`.  Newer versions would spit at you.

When there are non-aggregate columns in the `SELECT` (eg, `id`) that are not in the `GROUP BY` (which has only `orderid`), the selected items are picked somewhat randomly.

Suggest you change `id` to

```
orderid, MIN(id), MAX(id), COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(id)
```

`IN` is a red herring, not the cause.

If you need all the columns, not just `id`, you need to say so in the Question.  There are many Q&A about "grouwise-max".